# Exact each gmailapp threads subject line one at a time in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I want to set the variable "subject" to be the subject line of each email that matches my GmailApp.search criteria. Right now when it searches, it stores every subject line into the "subject" variable and I am unsure how to make it so I can perform subject[0] for the first subject, subject[1] for the second subject, etc

```
var threads = GmailApp.search("label:bills")

      for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

        var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

        for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {

          var subject = messages[m].getSubject()

        }

      }
```

If I have 2 emails that match the "bills" label, it will store both subject lines under "var = subject".

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? I cannot understand about "the first subject" and "the second subject". Do you want to retrieve put the subjects of messages for each thread, and put the subjects to  to 2 dimensional array by splitting to each thread like ``[["subject of message1 in thread1", "subject of message2 in thread1"],["subject of message1 in thread2", "subject of message2 in thread2"],,,]``?

Comment: @Tanaike If I have 2 emails, I want to loop through them and have the subject be in one variable so i can store it, then loop around again and store the second one.

Comment: In your script, it seems that you retrieve messages from each thread. In this case, what "2 emails" means?

Comment: @Tanaike if the label "Bills" matches 2 emails. I will result in having var = subject containing 2 subject lines.

Comment: I'm sorry. I cannot understand about "2 emails". Are those threads or messages in each thread? In order to understand correctly, can you provide a sample result you want? If you can do, please add it to your question.

Comment: @Tanaike If you execute the code I have above, and there are 2 email messages that contain the label "bills", the end result will be the variable "subject" containing:

"email #1 subject
email #2 subject"

Comment: I couldn't understand the result you want. I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182659/discussion-between-aaron-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of assigning the subject to a variable in you for loop, you need to push them into an array then you can access them like you wanted to with subject[1].

```
var subject = new Array();
var threads = GmailApp.search("label:bills")

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {

      subject.push(messages[m].getSubject());

    }

  }
```